# How do I write this C code involving Unicode?

Tags: c, word-frequency

I had a similar question asking what language would be best for this task, and Perl was the answer.  But I'm still curious how to resolve this with C.

I want to give this program a large text file filled with samples of German text taken from novels, newspapers, webpages.  I want a frequency list of all the words in the text file, sorted by most common word.  I need a list of the 3000 most common German words.

If this was just an ASCII problem, then this would be child's play for me.  After reading about Unicode all morning, I'm really surprised what a minefield it is.

How is this done in C?

I had a friend who put something together in Python, but he's still a beginner and his code took about 30 minutes on a 1.4 MB text file.

Comment: What is the character encoding of the large text file composing your corpus of words?  UTF-8?  UTF-16?  Something else?

Comment: I believe it is basically a *one liner* in Python, ignoring imports: `print(Counter(re.findall(r'(?u)\w+', open('input.txt').read())).most_common(3000))`. Not the fastest way, but it won't take 30 minutes.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield It's UTF-8.

Comment: -1 for doing no research. Just searching for [c] unicode here at SO would have gotten you several useful results. Take a look, e.g., at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114611/what-is-the-best-unicode-library-for-c (and notice the answer that got -8; ignore any mention wchar_t ... it isn't relevant to your needs).

Comment: Flagged for rudeness. No research was evident. I said nothing about "all the things", merely searching SO for [c] unicode. I gave you good help with the link I provided, but never again. Good luck ever getting help here if you insult the people you want help from.

Comment: P.S. It isn't possible to downvote comments.

Comment: Also, please read the site's FAQ before posting, notably http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette And it is a *responsibility* of the citizens of SO to vote questions and answers up and down to maintain and improve the quality of the site ... that's what I did, per http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down At least I gave a reason; people often don't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on encoding. Simplest one is UTF-8, in which you can simply store strings in `char*` arrays. Surprisingly, building a frequency list would be done using almost same code like in case of ASCII text. This is kind of UTF-8 magic, but it is why this encoding is so powerful!

There are a few thing that you should remember in this case:

1. Unicode provides more white characters than ASCII. You'll need a list of them to know where the words are separated. Happily, [Wikipedia has one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character).
2. Unicode is not always unequivocal. There are cases when different sequences produces the same character. It happens usually with composed characters: e.g. German `Ä` may be represented as:

   - character `U+00C4` - single letter `Ä`
   - sequence `U+0041 U+0308` - Latin letter `A` and diaeresis (umlaut) over it.

Happily, in German there are only seven non-English characters: `ÄäÖöÜüß`. You'd need to check how their alternative variants looks (e.g. [here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) on pages 4 and 5 you should find all German characters and their alternative forms).

Of course to solve both problems you will also need to know how all your findings are represented in UTF-8. This is described in [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629), page 3.

In case of other encodings (or other languages), I'd suggest not to deal with it yourself, but use some already existing library. If you are on Linux (or most of other Unices), you can use `iconv` function (`man 3 iconv`) to convert your text to UTF-8, and go as I described before.

Other choice is using some library that already deals with various Unicode variants. The most powerful is probably [ICU - International Components For Unicode](http://site.icu-project.org/), check their manuals to see how to perform your task using it.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified clearly the requirements of your program, but I can only think of two aspects that might need you to care about character identity:

1. If the input text is mixed case, you may want to map all words to the same case so that differently-cased versions of the same word are counted together.
2. If the input is in mixed normalization form (some characters precomposed, others decomposed) then you need to perform normalization to ensure that words that differ only in this way get counted together.

If for example your input were all-lowercase NFC, a program written with just ASCII in mind would work perfectly well for your task. Since this probably isn't the case, you need to evaluate your requirements. For just issue 1 (case), you can probably get by with using wide character stdio functions (or byte-oriented stdio and `mbsrtowcs`) and `towlower` to do case mapping. For issue 2 (normalization), you would need to either use an existing Unicode library for C or roll your own.

Comment: For German, _tschüß_ uppercases to _TSCHÜSS_, and _ue_ is an alternate form for _ü_, so `towlower()` falls short.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strings of `wchar_t` and the functions defined in `wchar.h` header file.

Answer (score 0):

If you could do it without a problem in ASCII, it shouldn't really be much harder in Unicode (in C99, at least).

Pretty much all of the standard library functions that work on strings and characters have wide character equivalents, and when you're working with wide characters, you'll never have to worry about the underlying encoding - one wide character represents one actual character. There's `iswupper`, `towupper`, `wcslen` and so on.

That's assuming you're working in a straightforward environment (e.g. UTF-8 system, UTF-8 text), as the locale will handle everything. If not, there's more work.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use system tools for this matter, this can be done if your system locale is set correctly. AWK is one you can use quite easily, **for example**:

```
BEGIN {
    FS="[^[:alpha:]]"
}
{
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if(array[$i]) {
            array[$i] += 1
        } else {
            array[$i]  = 1
        }
    }
}
END{
    for(i in array) {printf "%s = %d\n", i, array[i] }
}
```

invoke:

$ `awk -f script.awk German.txt | sort`

EDIT:

This is very *close* to what you are looking for.

Comment: Your script includes punctuation as parts of words, and I need a sorted list, but I see your point. Thanks.